# Data stored in select option is missing after create kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have a problem with missing data attributes in option after initialize kendo ui combobox.

My select look like this:

```
<select id="users">
    <option value="1" data-message="OK1">User 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-message="OK2">User 2</option>
</select>
```

now I create a kendo combobox based on this control:

```
$("#users").kendoComboBox({
    change: function() {
        alert($("#users option:selected").attr("data-message"));
    }
});
```

and the result is "undefined".

The 'data-message' stored value is missing. Is there any way to store this information in combobox?

I've found similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769175/delete-stored-jquery-data-data-element-option-after-creating-a-kendo-combobox but still no answer.

Here is telerik dojo to test the code above: http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO

Please help

Regards

Comment: You will have to find another way of doing it since when KendoUI decorates the select with their own wrapper they strip out your data. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think from the select you can only get the id and the text, not some other attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a bit unusual since other widgets like the treeview keep their data attributes when created like that; anyway, your best option is to use a data source instead:

```
<input id="users" />

$("#users").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: "User 1", value: "1", message: "OK1" },
        { text: "User 2", value: "2", message: "OK2"  }
    ],
    change: function() {
        console.log(this.dataItem().message);
    }
});
```